# Как изменить display в div при radio: checked (без JS!)?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/r0v7fkL6/16/

```
<div class="products">

<div class="bar_radios">
<input type="radio" name="bar" id="bar1">
<input type="radio" name="bar" id="bar2"> 
</div>
 
<div class="prod"></div> 
<div class="prod"></div> 
<div class="prod"></div> 
<div class="prod"></div> 
<div class="prod"></div> 
<div class="prod"></div> 
<div class="prod"></div>

</div>

.prod { display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #000; margin: 20px; }
 input#bar1:checked~.prod { display: block; }
 input#bar2:checked~.prod { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Расположите радиокнопки вне обёртки `.bar_radios`. Каскадные таблицы стилей потому и называются каскадными, что идут в одном направлении по нисходящей. Радиокнопки и нужные Вам блоки должны иметь одного общего родителя.

```css
.prod {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 20px;
}

input#bar1:checked~.prod {
  display: block;
}

input#bar2:checked~.prod {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">

  <input type="radio" name="bar" id="bar1">
  <input type="radio" name="bar" id="bar2">
  <div class="bar_radios"></div>

  <div class="prod"></div>
  <div class="prod"></div>
  <div class="prod"></div>
  <div class="prod"></div>
  <div class="prod"></div>
  <div class="prod"></div>
  <div class="prod"></div>

</div>
```